# Two red lines/bars in iTerm2 window and error message about session ending, what is going on here?

Tags: error, iterm, python

I've been [experimenting with threading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53656737/3904031) and running bits of python from iTerm in MacOS yesterday. Today I opened iTerm and *two windows* opened, one with thick red lines inside it. 
I received a Warning message from MacOS:

> A session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in profile “Default” is correct.

I said OK, the window with the red closed immediately, and I quit iTerm.

**Question:** What is really happening here? I've never seen red lines appear in iTerm2 or a session close immediately upon starting. Is this just "one of those things" or could something be seriously wrong that needs attention?

I only have one profile, called default.

---

> [image]

---

**edit:** after coaching in comments, I restarted iTerm2, same red lines. Engaged a *second brain cell* and realized I can move the error message out of the way, revealing the message in red in the iTerm2 window: `Broken Pipe`

[image]

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86767/discussion-on-question-by-uhoh-two-red-lines-bars-in-iterm2-window-and-error-mes) since it's unlikely to help further improvement of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this several times. It's caused by exiting an iTerm window. If you type `exit` in the window you'll be able to reproduce this behavior. I would check whatever command executes when iterm opens. This is defined in preferences.

Comment: Bingo! Yes, that happens just as you've described. *mea culpa:* I believe I probably typed that either because my threading mistakes left me with frozen or uncooperative behavior, or I thought I was at a python prompt (and forgot the parenthesis). Thank you, problem solved!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked and thanks for remembering to accept my answer.